# Allow multiple data types in a dataclass variable

Tags: python-dataclasses

Is there a way to allow a dataclass variable to have one of multiple data types?
(And it should also work in Python 3.7)

```
@dataclass
class C:
    index_range: tuple or str = "all"
```

I want index_range to have the default value string `"all"`, but also the possibility to take a tuple as a value.
(Later in the function I define that `"all"` means that all indices are used, but if a tuple is given only the elements between these numbers are used.)

Pylance always gives me the error that `"all" is not a Tuple`.

Are also more than two types possible, like tuple or None or str?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

```py
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class C:
    index_range: Union[tuple, str] = "all"
```